# Bitcoin has limited its scope

Tags: discussion

Your help page for on topic questions includes: "Questions about Bitcoin (or other crypto-currencies) that have no bearing on personal finance. (Bitcoin site)."

However, the Bitcoin site has narrowed its scope, so only Bitcoin specific questions are welcome there.

I've [posted a Q/A on our generic Meta site as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363121/where-can-i-ask-a-crypto-currency-or-blockchain-questions) after creating this page on [Cryptography Meta](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1511/1172) with a list of Stack Exchange sites and other resources. I've redirected here for questions relating to personal finance (please review the text to see if it matches with what is on topic here).

Your friendly neighborhood mod at the Crypto**graphy** site, Maarten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up. I've edited your generic meta post to highlight a couple of kinds of common off-topic questions.